# parameters in constructors for LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have my EF model like this:

```
 public class foo
    {
        private static TimeZoneInfo INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
        DateTime indianTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, INDIAN_ZONE);
        testData tD;

        public foo(testData localtD)
        {
            this.tD = localtD;
        }

        public String Name {
            get { return tD.Name; }
            set { }
        }
        public Double dueInDays { 
            get { return (indianTime - tD.StartDate).TotalDays; }
            set { } }
    }
```

and my API method is

```
        [Route("api/getSingleData")]
        [HttpGet]

        public dynamic getTestData()
        {

            var dataset2 = (from recordset in db.testDatas
                            select new foo(recordset) 
                            );
            return new { data = dataset2 };

        }
```

in `db.testDatas` i have date field and i want to return the difference between current date and the the startdate.

that database is more or less finalized and I cannot make changes in it to have this requirement fulfilled at the db query level. What is the fundamental mistake that i am doing for the error

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ
>   to Entities

to popup?

**And more importantly how should I modify the code to achieve the requirement?**

Thanks.

Comment: It's telling you precisely what the issue is.  `class foo` must use only a parameterless constructor.

Comment: true. what's the way out to solve achieve this.

Comment: Remove the parameter from the constructor and use object initialization syntax instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're trying to do.  This is as good as you're going to get...

```
public class foo
{
    private static TimeZoneInfo INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
    DateTime indianTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, INDIAN_ZONE);
    string _name;
    DateTime _startDate;

    public foo()
    {
    }

    public String Name {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public Double dueInDays 
    { 
        get { return (indianTime - _startDate).TotalDays; }
    }

    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get { return _startDate; }
        set { _startDate = value; }
    }
}
```

API Method:-

```
[Route("api/getSingleData")]
[HttpGet]
public dynamic getTestData()
{
    var dataset2 = (from recordset in db.testDatas
                    select new foo
                    { 
                        Name = recordset.Name, 
                        StartDate = recordset.StartDate 
                    });
    return new { data = dataset2 };
}
```

Alternatively you could keep foo as is and do....

```
[Route("api/getSingleData")]
[HttpGet]
public dynamic getTestData()
{

    var dataset2 = (from recordset in db.testDatas
                    select recordset 
                    ).ToList();

    return new { data = dataset2.select(r => new foo(r); };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a partial class to create a calculated field. Something like:

```
    public partial class testDatas
{
    public int duInDays
    {
        get 
        {
            TimeZoneInfo INDIAN_ZONE = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
            DateTime indianTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, INDIAN_ZONE);
            return (indianTime - StartDate).TotalDays;
        }
    }
}
```